# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number error when loading JSON data from Jinja2

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, web, jinja2

I am making a web site using the Google app-engine. I want to display a table from a Google SQL database. I pass DB data to .html from .py using Jinja2.

But I have a problem:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number" (line 88 in .html)
```

line 88 is `$.get(function({{jsondata|safe}})`; the full code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table;


    $(function(){
        $.get(function({{jsondata|safe}}){
            var jsonobj = JSON.parse({{jsondata|safe}});
            console.log(jsonobj);
            table = $('#userindex').dataTable({ 
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "sDom": "t<'row'<'col-xs-6 col-left'i><'col-xs-6 col-right'p>>",
                "bStateSave": false
            });
            $.each(jsonobj, function(key,value){
                table.fnAddData(value[0],value[1],value[2],value[3], value[4],value[5],value[6],value[7]);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I can see the JSON data when I press F12:

```
[[1, "u1", 27, "M", "ad1", "01043343883", "A34B", 0], [2, "u2", 24, "M", "ad2", "01099248819", "A35B", 0], [3, "u3", 0, "M", "ad3", "01043724865", "A36B", 0], [4, "u4", 0, "M", "ad4", "01043734865", "A37B", 0], [5, "u5", 24, "M", "ad5", "15555215554", "A38B", 4]]
```

And this is my Python code:

```
cursor.execute("""select no, u_name, age, gender, U_adress, phone, car_num, penalty from User;""")

data=cursor.fetchall() 
array_list=[]
for row in data:
    temp = (row[0],str(row[1]),row[2],str(row[3]),str(row[4]),row[5],str(row[6]),row[7])
    array_list.append(temp) 

jsondata=json.dumps(array_list)
db.commit()
db.close()

template_values = { 'jsondata':jsondata }

template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('User.html')
self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

[image]

Comment: `function({{jsondata|safe}})` is wrong, that is not where you would print your data, that is where the Parameter list goes

Comment: It's [`jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) not `jQuery.get(success, ...)`

Comment: Why are you doing a `get` if you run it immediately when the page has loaded? Wouldn't it be better in that case to just do it server side?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 2 different concepts to load data, interpolation and AJAX. Use one or the other, not both.

If you don't need to update the data live in the page, just use interpolation. Remove the AJAX call, just put the data from Python straight into a variable in the generated Javascript:

```js
$(function(){
    var jsonobj = {{jsondata|safe}};
    console.log(jsonobj);
    table = $('#userindex').dataTable({ 
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "sDom": "t<'row'<'col-xs-6 col-left'i><'col-xs-6 col-right'p>>",
        "bStateSave": false
    });
    $.each(jsonobj, function(key,value){
        table.fnAddData(value[0],value[1],value[2],value[3], value[4],value[5],value[6],value[7]);
    });
});
```